# How do I add additional hosts to HDP cluster

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have installed a HDP 2.2.4.2 cluster with 2 nodes both having CentOS 6.6 OS. I need to add one more host to this cluster but i didnt find any option to do this on the the ambari console (ambari version is 2.0) . Is there any way I can add more hosts to this cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the version of Ambari you have. For Ambari 1.7.0, 2.1.0 and 2.1.1:

Go to the 'Hosts' tab. In the top left corner you will see an 'Actions' drop down button; within that drop down menu you will see 'Add New Hosts'.

I don't have a 2.0.0 environment to test on but I would imagine if versions prior to 2.0.0 and after have it in the same spot, it would also be located in the same place.

You can also add hosts using the REST API. Details can be found on the [Ambari Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Add+a+host+and+deploy+components+using+APIs)

Comment: is there no way to add hosts with ambari version 2.0?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was under the 'Actions' dropdown

Answer (score 0):

On the top right corner there is an admin drop down button where you inspect your current nodes and add more as well.

Comment: The admin dropdown has an  option to manage ambari which in turn contains options to manage permissions, manage users+groups and manage views but i dont see any option to add more nodes

Comment: Did you login as admin on the Ambari front-end? See also this http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-apache-ambari-add-new-nodes-existing-cluster/

Comment: i have logged in as admin. I have noticed the add hosts option for ambari version 2.1 but am unable to find it with 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under hosts tabs. Screenshot will make it more clear
[image]